# Deleting a document from DocumentDB doesn't return the deleted document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core

I'm using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet) DocumentDB library in my MVC project. When I call `DeleteDocumentAsync` method in `DocumentClient` it returns `Null`. However, if you look at the method signature, it clearly states that it returns a document: `public Task<ResourceResponse<Document>> DeleteDocumentAsync(Uri documentUri, RequestOptions options = null);`

Also in the comments it sais, if that helps:

> // Returns:
>
> //     The task object representing the service response for the asynchronous operation.

Any idea why it doesn't return anything? I would expect it to return the deleted document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `DeleteDocumentAsync` does not return the deleted record itself, but instead returns a document specifying how many records have been deleted. If you for example run this:

```
var result = await collection.DeleteDocumentAsync(filter);
```

You can query the number of deleted records using `result.DeletedCount`.

Looking at the source code for the driver it actually returns a `DeleteResult` document, have a look at the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/DeleteResult.cs).